# Geting elements using Linq from two tables with a ICollection association?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I have two tables, `T1(NAME,T1_ID,NUMT1)` and `T2(NAME,POSITION,T2_ID)`, and a table that joins them (that basically show up as an association in Visual Studio) `ASSOTATION_Table(T1_ID,T2,ID)`.
What I want is to get the `T2.NAME` from `T2` where `T1.T1_ID= GivenId;`

SQL:

```sql
Select NAME FROM T2 where T2_ID = (SELECT T2_ID FROM ASSOTATION_Table where T1_ID=20);
```

Keep in mind that I can't access the `ASSOTATION_Table` using Linq because it's not a table anymore but an association and it's an `ICollection`.

[So T1 is RE_NATURE ,T2 is RE_MESURE and they are associated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGqnq.png) 
the association is presented by a table in the database :ASSOTATION_Table(T1_ID,T2,ID)

Comment: What kind of problem you have with LINQ query? Some error or unexpected results? Please refine your question with problem details and your code

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: I want an Link version of the SQL i just posted , i can't access the ASSOTATION_Table  so i dunno how to execute the code in Link

Comment: If your data context canvas properly contains an association, the `T1` class will have a property that is a collection of `T2` and vice versa. Then it will be `dx.T2.where(t => t.T1.T1_ID == 20)`.

Comment: If you ut a third (dummy) column into ASSOCIATION it will become a real table in the model.   Also, do T1 & T2 have a one-to-one or many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @GSerg yeah that what i have been trying to do all along but when i do t.T1. the properties of T1 doesn't show up i dunno why

Comment: @JamesCurran  its a one to many , and no it doesnt show up as a table in the model

Comment: @user8338592 A one-to-many shouldn't need a separate join table.  And it WILL appear as a table in the model IF you add another column to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an association in your model with navigation properties, you should be able to just follow the navigation property:

```
var ans = from t1 in RE_NATURE where t1.T1_ID == 20 select t1.RE_MESURE.Name
```